# Huge Binary size while ld Linking

Tags: linker, arm, ld, linker-scripts, cortex-a

I have a linker script that links code for imx6q(cortex-A9):

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-bigarm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
/* SEARCH_DIR(.) */
GROUP(libgcc.a libc.a)  
/*  INPUT (crtbegin.o crti.o crtend.o crtn.o) */

MEMORY {
/*  IROM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 96K */
    IRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x00900000, LENGTH = 256K
    IRAM_MMU (rwx): ORIGIN = 0x00938000, LENGTH = 24K
    IRAM_FREE(rwx): ORIGIN = 0x00907000, LENGTH = 196K
    DDR (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 1024M
}

/* PROVIDE(__cs3_heap_start = _end); */

SECTIONS {
    .vector (ORIGIN(IRAM) + LENGTH(IRAM) - 144 ):ALIGN (32) {
    __ram_vectors_start = . ;
    . += 72 ; 
    __ram_vectors_end = . ;
    . = ALIGN (4);  
    } >IRAM

    . = ORIGIN(DDR); 
    .text(.) :ALIGN(8) {
        *(.entry)
        *(.text)
        /* __init_array_start = .; */
        /* __init_array_end = .; */
        . = ALIGN (4);
        __text_end__ = .;
    } >DDR

    .data :ALIGN(8) {
        *(.data .data.*) 
        __data_end__ = .;
    } 

    .bss(__data_end__) : {
        . = ALIGN (4);
        __bss_start__ = .;
        *(.shbss)
        *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
        *(COMMON)
        __bss_end__ = .;
    }

    /*       . += 10K; */
    /*       . += 5K; */

    top_of_stacks = .;
    . = ALIGN (4);
    . += 8;
    free_memory_start = .;

    .mmu_page_table : {
    __mmu_page_table_base__ = .;
    . = ALIGN (16K);
    . += 16K;
    } >IRAM_MMU 

    _end = .;
    __end = _end;
    PROVIDE(end = .);
}
```

When i built, the binary size is just 6 KB. But i can not add any initialized variable. When i add an initialized variable, the binary size jumps to ~246 MB. Why is that? I tried to link the data segment at location following text section by specifying exact location and also providing >DDR for the data segment. Even though this seem to reduce the binary size back to 6 KB, the binary fails to boot. How can i keep my code in the DDR and the data, bss, stack and heap in the internal ram itself, with light binary size?

I read in another thread that " using MEMORY tag in linker script should solve the problem of memory waste", How can this be done?

[linker script wastes my memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831821/linker-script-wastes-my-memory/40501816#40501816)

Plese do ask if anything else needed. I don't have any experience with linker script. Please help

The readelf --sections output of the binary with no initialized data given is as follows,

```
There are 19 section headers, starting at offset 0xd804:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .vector           NOBITS          0093ff80 007f80 000048 00  WA  0   0 32
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        10000000 008000 0016fc 00  AX  0   0  8
  [ 3] .text.vectors     PROGBITS        100016fc 0096fc 000048 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 4] .text.proc        PROGBITS        10001744 009744 000034 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 5] .bss              NOBITS          0093ffc8 007fc8 000294 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 6] .mmu_page_table   NOBITS          00938000 008000 004000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 7] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 009778 00001f 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 8] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 009797 00003d 00      0   0  1
  [ 9] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 0097d8 000108 00      0   0  8
  [10] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 0098e0 0018a7 00      0   0  1
  [11] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 00b187 00056f 00      0   0  1
  [12] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 00b6f6 00080e 00      0   0  1
  [13] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 00bf04 000430 00      0   0  4
  [14] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 00c334 0013dd 01  MS  0   0  1
  [15] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 00d718 000020 00      0   0  8
  [16] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00d738 0000cb 00      0   0  1
  [17] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00dafc 000740 10     18  60  4
  [18] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 00e23c 000511 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

and The readelf --sections output of the binary with initialized data given is ,

```
 There are 20 section headers, starting at offset 0xd82c:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .vector           NOBITS          0093ff80 007f80 000048 00  WA  0   0 32
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        10000000 008000 0016fc 00  AX  0   0  8
  [ 3] .text.vectors     PROGBITS        100016fc 0096fc 000048 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 4] .text.proc        PROGBITS        10001744 009744 000034 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 5] .data             PROGBITS        0093ffc8 007fc8 000004 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 6] .bss              NOBITS          0093ffcc 007fcc 000294 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 7] .mmu_page_table   NOBITS          00938000 008000 004000 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 8] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 009778 00001f 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 9] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 009797 00003d 00      0   0  1
  [10] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 0097d8 000108 00      0   0  8
  [11] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 0098e0 0018b6 00      0   0  1
  [12] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 00b196 000580 00      0   0  1
  [13] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 00b716 00080e 00      0   0  1
  [14] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 00bf24 000430 00      0   0  4
  [15] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 00c354 0013dd 01  MS  0   0  1
  [16] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 00d738 000020 00      0   0  8
  [17] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00d758 0000d1 00      0   0  1
  [18] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00db4c 000770 10     19  62  4
  [19] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 00e2bc 000513 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

Hope this is enough...!!!

Note: I am using **arm-none-eabi-gcc** for linking.

Comment: Can you post the output of `readelf --sections` for your binaries?

Comment: The output has been added. In the second case, the size of the binary becomes ~246MB as compired to 6 KB in the previous one....

Comment: It is obvious (and similar problems (or Q/A) are on SO).  `IRAM LENGTH = 256K` with  `DDR(256MB) - IRAM(9MB) ~=256MB` with your binary increases to 246MB. [Read about VMA/LMA](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html) and use these as a search term.  A **BINARY** must be a contiguous chunk of well binary!  There is no section information.  Do you see the issue?  The gnu LD scripts have `AT` type directive and the LMA/VMA to address this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run code from RAM on ARM architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137214/how-to-run-code-from-ram-on-arm-architecture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not experienced with linker scripts then either use one that just works or make or borrow a simpler one.  Here is a simple one, and this should demonstrate what is most likely going on.

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x100
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0x100
    alice : ORIGIN = 0x00003000, LENGTH = 0x100
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .data : { *(.text*) } > ted
    .bss : { *(.text*) } > alice
}
```

First program

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
mov r0,r1
mov r1,r2
b .
```

not meant to be a real program just creating some bytes in a segment is all.

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00001000 001000 00000c 00  AX  0   0  4
```

12 bytes in .text which is at address 0x1000 in memory which is exactly what we told it to do.

If I use -objcopy a.elf -O binary a.bin I get a 12-byte file as expected, the "binary" file format is a memory image, starting with the first address that has some content in the address space and ending with the last byte of content in the address space.  so instead of 0x1000+12 bytes, the binary is 12 bytes ad the user has to know it needs to be loaded at 0x1000.

So change this up a little:

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
mov r0,r1
mov r1,r2
b .
.data
some_data: .word 0x12345678

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00001000 001000 00000c 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS        00002000 002000 000004 00  WA  0   0  1
```

Now we have 12 bytes at 0x1000 and 4 bytes at 0x2000, so -O binary has to give us one memory image from the first defined byte to the last so that would be 0x1000+4.

Sure enough 4100 bytes that is exactly what it did.

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
mov r0,r1
mov r1,r2
b .
.data
some_data: .word 0x12345678
.bss
some_more_data: .word 0
```

which gives

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00001000 001000 00000c 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS        00002000 002000 000004 00  WA  0   0  1
  [ 3] .bss              NOBITS          00003000 003000 000004 00  WA  0   0  1
```

Now I only got a 4100-byte file, and that is actually not surprising, it is assumed that the bootstrap is going to zero .bss  So that didn't grow the "binary" file.

There is an intimate relationship.  A system-level design.  Between the linker script and the bootstrap.  For what it appears you are trying to do (just ram no rom) you can probably get away with a much simpler linker script, on par with the one I have but if you care about .bss being zeroed then there are some tricks you can use:

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x3000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .data : { *(.text*) } > ram
}
```

make sure there is at least one .data item and your "binary" will have the complete image with bss already zeroed, the bootstrap simply needs to set the stack pointer(s) and jump to main (if this is for C).

Anyway, hopefully, you can see that the jump from 12 bytes to 4100 bytes was because of the addition of a .data element and the "binary" format having to pad the "binary" file so that the file was a memory image from the lowest address with data to the highest address with data (from 0x1000 to 0x2000+sizeof(.data)-1 in this case).  Change the linker script, the 0x1000, and the 0x2000 and this all changes.  Swap them put .text at 0x2000 and .data at 0x1000, now the "binary" file has to be 0x2000-0x1000+sizeof(.text)  rather than 0x2000-0x1000+sizeof(.data).  or 0x100C bytes instead of 0x1004.  go back to the first linker script and make .data at 0x20000000 now the "binary" will be 0x20000000-0x1000+sizeof(.data) because that is how much information including padding is required to make a memory image in a single file.

It is most likely that is what is going on. As demonstrated here the file size went from 12 bytes to 4100 by simply adding one word of data.

EDIT.

Well if you noload the data then your initialized variable won't be initialized, it is that simple

```c
unsigned int x = 5;
```

will not be a 5 if you discard (NOLOAD) .data.

As has been stated and stated again, you can have the data put in the .text sector and then use more linker script foo, to have the bootstrap find that data.

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x100
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0x100
    alice : ORIGIN = 0x00003000, LENGTH = 0x100
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .data : { *(.text*) } > ted AT > bob
    .bss : { *(.text*) } > alice AT > bob
}
```

This creates a 16 byte "binary" file.  the 12 bytes of instruction and the 4 bytes of .data.  But you don't know where the data is unless you do some hardcoding which is a bad idea.  This is where things like **bss_start** and **bss_end** are found in your linker script.

something like this

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x100
    ted : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0x100
    alice : ORIGIN = 0x00003000, LENGTH = 0x100
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
    .data : {
        __data_start__ = .;
        *(.data*)
    } > ted AT > bob
    __data_end__ = .;
    __data_size__ = __data_end__ - __data_start__;
    .bss : { *(.text*) } > alice AT > bob
}
```

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov r0,r1
    mov r1,r2
    b .
    
    
hello:
    .word __data_start__
    .word __data_end__
    .word __data_size__
    
    .data
    some_data: .word 0x12345678
```

which gives us.

```
Disassembly of section .text:
    
00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   e1a00001    mov r0, r1
    1004:   e1a01002    mov r1, r2
    1008:   eafffffe    b   1008 <_start+0x8>
    
0000100c <hello>:
    100c:   00002000    andeq   r2, r0, r0
    1010:   00002004    andeq   r2, r0, r4
    1014:   00000004    andeq   r0, r0, r4
    
Disassembly of section .data:
    
00002000 <__data_start__>:
    2000:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

and the toolchain/linker creates and fills those defined names in the linker script, and then fills them into your code when it resolves those externals.  Then your bootstrap needs to use those variables (and more that I didn't include here where to find the .data in the .text you know from the above that there are 4 bytes and they need to land at 0x2000 but where in the 0x1000 .text area are those 4 bytes found?  More linker script foo.  Also, note the gnu linker scripts are very sensitive as to where you define those variables. before or after the squiggly brackets can have different results.

This is why I mentioned it appeared you were using ram.  If this is a rom based target and you want .data and zeroed .bss then you pretty much have to put the .data and the size and location of .bss in the flash/rom area and the bootstrap has to copy and zero.  Alternatively, you can choose not to use .data nor .bss

```c
unsigned int x=5;
unsigned int y;
```

instead

```c
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
...
x=5;
y=0;
```

Yes, it is not as efficient binary size-wise, but linker scripts are very much toolchain dependent, and with gnu for example over time the linker script language/rules change, what worked on a prior major version of gnu ld doesn't necessarily work on the current or next, I have had to re-architect my minimal linker script over the years as a result.

As demonstrated here, you can use your command line tools to experiment with settings and locations and see what the toolchain has produced.

Bottom line it sounds like you added some information in .data, but then state you want to NOLOAD it, basically meaning that .data isnt there/used your variables are not initialized correctly, so why bother changing the code to cause all this to happen only to have it not work anyway?  Either has .data and use it right, have the right bootstrap and linker script pair, or if it is ram only just pack it all up into the same ram space, or don't use the "binary" format you are using, use elf or ihex or srec or other.

Another trick depending on your system is to build the binary for ram, all packed up, then have another program that wraps around that binary runs from rom and copies to ram and jumps.   Take the 16 byte program above, write another that includes those 16 bytes from that build, and copies them to 0x1000 and then branches to 0x1000.  Depending on the system and the flash/rom technology and interface you may wish to do this anyway, the system from my day job uses a spi flash to boot, which are known to have read-disturb problems and are...spi... So the fastest, cleanest, most reliable solution, is to do the copy jump before doing anything else.  Making the linker script much easier as a free side effect.

Comment: The problem seems to be gone when i added (NOLOAD) to the data sections. Is there anyway to make sure?

Comment: `NOLOAD`  implies that the data section is not part of the binary.  What you have to do (if you don't have only BSS or zero initialized memory) is put the initial data values in the main image and have boot code copy it to the final location. (LMA load memory address and VMA virtual memory address which is the actual final absolute address that all assembler should reference),